# CQL UPDATE a set<bigint> with join query

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have to delete few data from a table using CQL based on some condition which will fetch data from another table. But I am unable to form the query.

Here is the table details from where I need to delete data :

```
Table Name : xyz_group
Columns : dept_id [int] , sub_id [set<bigint>]
PRIMARY KEY (Partition key) : dept_id
```

There can be same sub_id for multiple dept_id. The data is something like below :

```
dept_id     |     sub_id
-------------------------------
1098        |  345678298, 24579123, 8790455308
2059        |  398534698, 24579123, 8447659928
3467        |  311209878, 24579123, 8790455308, 987654321,
```

I need to remove only ---> **24579123, 8790455308** from all the rows.

And here is my **SELECT** query which will fetch the data from another table **abc_list** which is to be removed from table **xyz_group**

```
select sub_id from abc_list where sub_name='XYZ';
```

The output for the above query will give me a list of **sub_id** which I want to remove from the table **xyz_group**. So basically I want to update the set by removing data from the set. Something like below :

```
UPDATE xyz_group SET sub_id = sub_id - [ query result from above select query ] WHERE dept_id in (1098, 2059, 3467, ...);
```

I have tried to remove one element from the set, but I am getting the below error :

```
UPDATE xyz_group SET sub_id = sub_id - [ 24579123 ] WHERE dept_id in (1098, 2059, 3467, ...);

Error : Column sub_id type set<bigint> is not compatible with type list<int>
```

The tables has around >50k records. Can anyone please help to form the single correct query to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query is working for me now :

```
UPDATE xyz_group SET sub_id = sub_id - { 24579123 } WHERE dept_id in (1098, 2059, 3467, ...);
```

But I am doing a 2 step process to update the table. First collecting the required **sub_id** and then using a separate **UPDATE** query to update the table.Not able to do in a single query.